# ItemTemplate inside UpdatePanel inside GridView

Tags: datagridview, webforms, updatepanel, itemtemplate

I have a GridView that has some ItemTemplates. Those itemtemplates contain some server controls inside an UpdatePanel.
Whene i make an asynchronous postback to the server and use "FindControl", i get a NullPointerException because in my code behind i'm using FindControl in this way :

```
GridViewRow row = (sender as DropDownList).Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
                DropDownList ddlAffaireDr= (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlAffaireDr");
```

It seems that because the gridview is not inside an updatepanel, so i can not reference its row. And i don't want to make my gridview in an update panel.
ASPX Code :

```
<asp:GridView  Width="100%"
  ID="tempsBudgetGV" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TempsId" EmptyDataText="Pas de lignes." OnRowDataBound="tempsBudgetGV_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="true" OnPreRender="tempsBudgetGV_PreRender">
                        <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contrat">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel99" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAffaireDr" runat="server" CssClass="ArtSup input-large form-control" ></asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: can you post the full code behind in the class file and the aspx code?

Comment: can you post that code behind method too?

Comment: already did that, it's the first code, i need to reference my server control with findcontrol method. but findcontrol is based on the gridview row wich actually is not returned to the server due to the updatepanel.

Comment: Please put on the whole method that contains the code you have put here.! Only when you let us know under which event or method you are handling find control we will be able to help you.